# API Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

I am having an error when people register or try to login, it throws me the following error, but it happens sometimes,
[image]

my code is the following
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Please consider copying/pasting sections of your code into future questions instead of just screenshots. This makes it easier for others to provide an answer.

Comment: Do not use screenshots for text. Copy and paste the text into your post.

Answer (score 1):

`res.send` can only be called once. In the `bcrypt.compare` callback, `res.send` is called twice (for both statuses `201` and `200`). Also, you must use a return statement after `res.send` or return `res.send`. This is because the code continues after executing the function.

You can also:

- Change the status code for a false result to `400` - best practice
- Remove the `500` as it is never reached.

I have applied these changes to my code below.

Fixed code:

```
...
if (!result) {
    return res.status(400).json({
            error: "User or password invalid",
        })
    }

    const userForToken = {
        id: users._id,
        name: users.name,
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(userForToken, process.env.SECRET)

    res.status(200).send({
        name: users.name,
        email: users.email,
        token,
        result: true,
        id: users._id,
    })
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`res.status().send()` doesn't exit the function like `return`, so you cannot use it like `return`. You are getting this error because you are sending a response more than once.

I would suggest structuring your logic to build a `Response` object, then send the response once it is built.

Example Response Object:

```
class Response{
    constructor(status, body){
        this.status = status;
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
...

var response;

if(!result){
    response = new Response(201, {error: "User or password invalid"});
}

if(!response){
    const userForToken = {
        id: users._id,
        name: users.name,
    }

    const token = jwt.sign(userForToken, process.env.SECRET)

    response = new Response(200, {name: users.name, email: users.email, token: token, result: true, id: users._id})
}

res.status(response.status).send(response.body);
```